# Can Loki control Vision?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

As we all know Vision is made with the Mind-stone which was a part of Loki's staff.

Loki has controlled this staff for decades.

So does that mean Loki can also control Vision?

Comment: No, Loki *used* the staff for a couple of days. The staff's power came from the Mind Stone.

Answer (score 16):

The thing you're calling Loki's staff -- the object that housed the Mind Stone -- is not something Loki has had for decades. It was actually given to him by Thanos, as part of his plan to have the Chitauri invade Earth. He only had it for a short time, before losing it to SHIELD.

Even while Loki had the scepter, he wasn't controlling the Mind Stone directly; he was using a tool purpose-built to harness its power in specific ways (much like the Tesseract or the Aether). The raw power of the Stone would likely have overpowered even him.

So no, there's not really any reason to believe Loki can control Vision. (At least, not because of the scepter).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are confused. Loki never controlled the staff. The staff was used as a containment vessel for the mind stone. Loki used it for the power it gave as well as leading the chitaui to Earth. Vision is made from vibrainium, the mind stone, and a combination of Ultron and Jarvis's matrix. Just because Loki used the scepter with the mind stone in it for a little while doesn't mean he has control of whoever possesses it. **No, Vision can't be controlled by Loki in any way for having possessed the Mind Stone.**

Answer (score 0):

Loki's scepter was used to contain the mind stone. It is used as a weapon with just a small fraction of the power within the mind stone. Thanos had given Loki the scepter so he could invade Earth, implying he hasn't been in possession of the mind stone for "decades." Just because a person uses an infinity stone doesn't mean they have power over it no matter the length of time they have had possession. Vision is made with the mind stone and vibranium tissue, which is what gives him the power he possesses, however he is not controlled by the mind stone, but rather it serves as a life force to him.. Even when portrayed as a human he still possesses the mind stone although it is hidden. In conclusion no, **Loki has no control over Vision in any way shape or form.**

Comment: Did you mean to post this as a new answer?   It seems like it should have been an edit to your previous answer.